# Does a $p$-adic power series $F(x,y)=\sum_{i,j \geq 0}b_{ij}x^iy^j \in \mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]$ have finitely many zeros in $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb C_p}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-analysis

Let us consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$ with ring of integers $\mathbb Z_p$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

Then any $p$-adic power series $f(x)=\sum_{n>0}a_nx^n \in \mathbb Z_p[[x]]$ with weierstrass degree $l$ has $$\text{only $l$ zeros in $\mathfrak{m}$}.$$ This is due to $p$-adic Weierstrass preparation Theorem, which says $$f(x)=u(x) \cdot p(x),$$ where $u(x)$ is a unit power series in $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$ and $p(x)=x^l+\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}c_nx^n$ is the distinguished polynomial of degree $l$ and non-leading coefficients $c_i \in \mathfrak{m}$.

The upshot is that $f(x)$ has only finitely many zeros in $\mathfrak{m}$.

My question:

> Can we say whether a 2-variable power series $F(x,y)=\sum_{i,j>0}b_{ij}x^iy^j \in \mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]$ have finitely many zeros in $\mathfrak{m}$ ?

---

I am not aware if there is any other argument besides arguing along Weierstrass preparation Theorem (just we did in 1-variable case).

From [Wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem#Tate_algebras), it is mentioned that there is a Weierstrass Preparation Theorem for Tate Algebra of multivariable power series. But no more given there in the link.

In [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem#Complex_analytic_functions), there is a multivariable Weierstrass Preparation Theorem for complex( $\mathbb C$) valued functions. According to this, pick one variable $x$ then we can write $$F(x,y)=w(x)h(y)$$ with Weierstrass polynomial $w(x)$ and $h(0) \neq 0$ is analytic function.

Can we do the same in $p$-adic complex analysis in the field $\mathbb C_p:=\widehat{\bar{\mathbb Q}_p}$ ? If so, then $w(x)$ will have finitely many, say $r$, zeros in $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb C_p}$. Now, again we can use Weierstrass Preparation Theorem for $h(y)$ and again $h(y)$ will have finitely many, say $s$, zeros in $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb C_p}$. Thus $F(x,y)$ will have at most $rs$ zeros in $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb C_p}$. This may be the possible generalization of Weierstrass Preparation Theoerm for $2$-variable $p$-adic power series.

In other word, $F(x,y)$ will have only finitely many zeros in $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb C_p}$.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Taking $F(x,y) = xy$ shows that there can be infinitely many zeros in $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: @JohnDoyle, so what is happening here between two variable power series and one variable power power series ? In one variable case, it has only finitely many zeroes in $\mathfrak{m}$ but unlikely in 2 variable power series.

Comment: Weierstrass preparation is about comparing power series to polynomials. But a polynomial in two variables already has a positive-dimensional solution set.

Comment: A counterexample is $y - x$. Why should you not expect the zero set to be finite? Classically, the zero set of a nice function $\mathbf R^2\to\mathbf R$ should be $1$-dimensional (a curve), and more generally the zero set of a nice function $\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$ should be $(n-1)$-dimensional (a hypersurface). So we shouldn't expect a single power series in several variables to have a finite zero set. But with two power series in two variables not in a degenerate setting (e.g., don't use the same power series twice), we might expect a finite zero set (like two curves crossing in the plane).

Comment: Since $\mathbf C_p$ is not locally compact, keep in mind the distinction between finiteness and discreteness. For example, $\log(1+x) \in \mathbf Q_p[[x]]$ converges on $\mathfrak m_{\mathbf C_p}$ and there it has an infinite zero set that is discrete: all $\zeta - 1$ where $\zeta$ runs over all $p$-power roots of unity. If $\zeta$ and $\zeta'$ are distinct $p$-power roots of unity in $\mathbf C_p$, then $|(\zeta - 1) - (\zeta' - 1)|_p = |\zeta - \zeta'|_p \geq (1/p)^{1/(p-1)} > 0$. But for each finite extension $K/\mathbf Q_p$, the zero set of $\log(1+x)$ in $\mathfrak m_K$ is finite.

Comment: I think you’ve misunderstood the point of WPrep. Your $w(x)$ does not have coefficients that are constants, but rather analytic functions in the other variable.

Comment: @Lubin, Yes, absolutely, professor Lubin.

Comment: @KConrad, what about a function $\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$ according to your 1st comment ? I think in that case, we have to solve a system of equations and the common solution set may be finite.

Comment: Sure, $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns is certainly more likely to be finite if the equations are "independent".  Or maybe I should say the solution is more likely to be discrete or 0-dimensional.  The failure of local compactness of $\mathbf C_p$ creates a distinction between discreteness and finiteness in closed bounded subsets, which is a contrast to $\mathbf R^n$.  Anyway, you only offered a single power series in two variables, so it's unlikely that the zero set will be finite unless you bring in a second power series.

Comment: @KConrad, thank you so much. Yes I understand the answer to my main question is negative, as you mentioned in your 1st comment. I just got curious about and so asked about the map $\textbf{R}^n \to \textbf{R}^n$. A warm wishes for new year.